# How to show TabNavigator only for some screens but not for others? - The component for route 'TabNavigator' must be a React component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

User should go first to the Authentication screen and, once authenticated, he should be redirected to the Tab Navigation screens.

I tried the following approach, which didn't work. The error I got was - **The component for route 'TabNavigator' must be a React component**:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Authentication: Authentication,
    TabNavigator: TabNavigator
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Authentication"
  }
);
```

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: { screen: Profile },
    Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
    History: { screen: History }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Dashboard"
  }
);
```

```
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

How can I make this happen?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Double check your `Profile`, `Dashboard`, `History` to see whether they are exported properly

Comment: they are @TuanLuong